# Reload JavaScript function via ajax / re-read jsf-bean value

Tags: javascript, ajax, jsf

I have a JavaScript function using a value from a backing bean, like `var x = #{bean.value}`.

On page load, the value for `x` is final until the page is being reloaded (since EL is being replaced by its actual value string).

However, the bean's `value` might change due to ajax requests.
How can I achieve that `x` gets updated?

Here's an excerpt from my xml (using primefaces' calendar component) to clarify:

```
<p:calendar beforeShowDay="highlightDays" ... />

<script>
   function highlightDays(){
      var highlightedDays= #{bean.specialDays()};
      // set css...
   }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the RequestContext to do such an update from the bean:

```
RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().execute("highlightedDays = " + specialDays());
```

And the javascript variable should be on the window scope, meaning that you should define the var outside the scope of the function.

```
highlightedDays= #{bean.specialDays()};      
function highlightDays(){
  //make use of the var  
}
```